# How to prevent li text going under the button

Tags: html, css

How can i prevent the text going below the button when it gets too large?

**HTML**

```
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500;900&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<html>
<body>
<div class="app">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item" id="item-input"/>

    <button id="item-button">Add</button>
    <ul id="items">
      <li><button class="remove">X</button>Hamburger</li>
      <li><button class="remove">X</button>Milk</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is what is happening**

[Text going under the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVCqz.png)

**And this is the CodePen**

https://codepen.io/ReaperClown/pen/oNZprmY

Comment: there is possible no word that is this long without a space. Test your code with some realistic words.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 3):

Change `break-word` to `break-all`:

```
li {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Don't need display: flex, just this answer to fix it.

Comment: Yes, flex-box would only add more hassle to the initial design. This is the simplest way in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Should do the trick..

```
#items li {
  display:flex;
  word-break: break-all;  // Not needed but might fix the overflow issue later on
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify whether line breaks should appear wherever your `<li>` text would overflow its content box with [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break). Using `word-break: break-all;` on your `<li>` elements will make sure that line breaks appear when a list item has a long line of text and overflows its content box.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #101011;

  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  background-color: #a8bfb6;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em 2em;

  width: 400px;

  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #2b2b2e;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  word-break: break-all; 
}

#items {
  display: table-cell;
}

.remove {
  border: none;
  background-color: #f4d58d;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  word-wrap: inherit;
  position: relative;
}

#item-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f4d58d;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Shopping List</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item" id="item-input"/>

        <button id="item-button">Add</button>
        <ul id="items">
          <li><button class="remove">X</button>Hamburger</li>
          <li><button class="remove">X</button>Milk</li>
          <li><button class="remove">X</button>abschbaskjhdbaksdhjbalskdjabsdklahbsdlkajsbdalksjdbalksdj</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ ImmortalSamuraiFenix Does this answer your question?